# Setting context path for routes in Compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I'm building a Compojure webapp composed of two Clojure project. The first one is a webapp to visualize some data, the second one is a more complex application which need to use the first one.

I want to be able to run both application at the same time with **run-jetty** from the second project. This would allow the second webapp to call the URL from the first one to get the visualization.

I'm using the **context** macro from Compojure, here are the routes for the second app:

```
(def second-project-main-routes
  [
   (context "/second" request
            (GET "/viewsession" {session :session} (str session))
            (GET "/resetsession" [] (reset-session))
             ... other routes here ...
            (route/resources "/"))
  ])


(def second-all-routes
(concat second-project-main-routes
         first-project-routes)


(def second-app
  (-> (handler/site (apply routes second-all-routes))
      (wrap-base-url)))

;; to comment when building the JAR:
(defonce second-server (run-jetty #'second-app {:join? false :port 8080}))
```

and here the routes for the first app:

```
(def first-project-routes
[(context "/first" request
        (GET "/" [] (index-page))
        (route/files "/" {:root (str (System/getProperty "user.dir") "/data/public")})
        (route/resources "/"))])
```

I have two main.js files.  One in **firstproject/resources/public/js/app/main.js** and one 
**in secondproject/resources/public/js/app/main.js**

When I browse the url **localhost:8080/first/app/js/main.js** I get the main.js of the **second** project. Why that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say how you are combining these and running, so I don't know how your classpath is set up.  However, you have the same route/resource configuration on both contexts, so they will both pull content from "public" on your classpath.  If both firstproject/resources and secondproject/resources are on the classpath, you are going to have conflicts.  In this case, it seems secondproject/resources is seen first, so that's what gets pulled.

Maybe you should change "public" on first and second apps to be "public-first" and "public-second", respectively.  Then you use the appropriate resource location to each context without worrying about the classpath. Ex:

```
(route/resources "/" {:root "public-first"})
(route/resources "/" {:root "public-second"})
```